# BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateRequired|string does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm currently working on an API for a car dealership, small school project.

In the CarController, I'm working on the POST request for adding a car and I'm having some problems with the validation of data.

This is a sample of the kind of data I'd be receiving:

```php
{
  "model": "Q5",
  "brand": "Audi",
  "year": 2008,
  "price": 44000,
  "color": "blue",
  "traction": "4x4",
  "motor": {
    "type": "gasoline",
    "hp": 256,
    "turbo": false,
    "cylinders": 4,
    "motor_liters": 2.0
  },
  "user_id": 1
}
```

Considering the format, I wrote the validation like this:

```php
$request->validate([
            'model' => 'required|string',
            'brand' => 'required|string',
            'year' => 'required|integer',
            'price' => 'required|numeric',
            'color' => 'required|string',
            'traction' => 'required|string',
            'motor' => [
                'type' => 'required|string',
                'hp' => 'required|integer',
                'turbo' => 'required|boolean',
                'cylinders' => 'required|integer',
                'motor_liters' => 'required|numeric'
            ],
            'user_id' => 'required|integer'
        ]);
```

However, when making the request, it gives me the following error from the Validator:

```
BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateRequired|string does not exist.
```

At this point I don't know if it's a typo, bad formatting or I have to handle nested JSONs differently, considering I have a UserController with a POST request that looks like this:

```php
$request->validate([
            'username' => 'required|string|min:5',
            'password' => 'required|string'
        ]);
```

And it works perfectly.

If you want to try the API yourselves here's the link to the [repo](https://github.com/ASB24/chimera-dealership-api).

Comment: you are using the array notation (as you can't validate nested data the way you have it) for validation rules so each rule has to be an element of the array, you can't mix the string notation with it ... so it is looking for a method named `validateRequired|string` because you are giving it the rule named `required|string`, which doesn't exist as those are 2 separate rules ... please read the docs on validating nested data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to validate nested fields you have to use dot notation and not nest arrays:

```
$request->validate([
            'model' => 'required|string',
            'brand' => 'required|string',
            'year' => 'required|integer',
            'price' => 'required|numeric',
            'color' => 'required|string',
            'traction' => 'required|string',
            'motor.type' => 'required|string',
            'motor.hp' => 'required|integer',
            'motor.turbo' => 'required|boolean',
            'motor.cylinders' => 'required|integer',
            'motor.motor_liters' => 'required|numeric',
            'user_id' => 'required|integer'
        ]);
```